# Nextjs form data in server action is not an json object when using names with square brackets for inputs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In my nextjs form, I have inputs with names containing square brackets like

```
store[name]
store[homePage]
store[domain]
```

and I am using a server action to handle this form submission.
but the received form data is a map like, i.e. to get the store name I write

```
formData.get('store[name]')
```

and so on.

how to get the submitted data as an object like

```
const store = formData.get('store');
```

this store is expected to be an object with the properties {name, homePage, domain}

like body parser in express js

searched for a solution but with no luck

Answer (score 1):

I could use `lodash` to achieve this.

```
import _ from "lodash";

export default function parseFormData(formData) {
    const object = {};
    for (const [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
        _.set(object, key, value);
    }
    return object;
}

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("store[name]", "Some Name");
formData.append("store.homePage", "https://example.com");
formData.append("store.domain[0]", "example.com");
formData.append("address[city]", "New York");
formData.append("address[state]", "NY");
formData.append("categories[0]", "category1");
formData.append("categories[1]", "category2");
formData.append("nested[obj][prop1]", "value1");
formData.append("nested[obj][prop2]", "value2");
formData.append("simpleName", "Simple Value");
formData.append("complex[0][p][a][0]", "pppp");
formData.append("complex[0][p][b]", "dddd");
formData.append("complex[1][p][a][0]", "aaa");
formData.append("complex[1][p][b]", "bbb");

const dataObject = parseFormData(formData);
console.log(dataObject);
console.log(dataObject.complex);
```

output:

```
{
  store: {
    name: 'Some Name',
    homePage: 'https://example.com',
    domain: [ 'example.com' ]
  },
  address: { city: 'New York', state: 'NY' },
  categories: [ 'category1', 'category2' ],
  nested: { obj: { prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2' } },
  simpleName: 'Simple Value',
  complex: [ { p: [Object] }, { p: [Object] } ]
}
[ { p: { a: [Array], b: 'dddd' } }, { p: { a: [Array], b: 'bbb' } } ]
```